# Array.find return type is correct but is errorneous

Tags: typescript

I try to find a way to hint the expected return type of `Array.find()` where typescript warn me it is not compatible.

[The code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQEQBcCeAHApugLzqzrQpqYBc0EmATgJYB2A5gNyWoDEY0RaAAZu0YAHsW9BgFdgmcQwAUNOo1ZsAlIlFpomABZMIAOkwD9XPQF8ktpKEgwAQjr1Y8hEs-KjV0jS5RCSlGOQVlf3V2bWQ9PUNjMwtMKzRbexwCOBAQC3gAH2hnJCz8aAARMEx+QVhcgG0AXSQkADMZFnkmSX0GcRkAN3wlMAYGaiqazWpYAs6AE3w21nwFtzQGfEwZBhZoMYYTFZYFpQAPAQA+aHOzTwEiQVJ0TS5rIA)

```
class A {
    "type"="A" 
    t: string;
    #a = 0
    constructor(t: string) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}

class B {
    "type"="B" 
    t: string;

    constructor(t: string) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}

type All = A | B

function trouve(arr:All[]):A {
    return arr.find(x => x.type === "A");
}
```

Typescript underlines the `return` line with this message :

> Type 'All | undefined' is not assignable to type 'A | undefined'

I understand that the parser can be unable to understand it, I just would like to remove this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assert that the return value of `trove` is definitely `A`.

```
function trouve(arr:All[]) {
    return arr.find(x => x.type === "A") as A;
}
```